# pythonic way to split list?

Tags: list, split, python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python)

I Have a function like below:

```
def split_list(self,my_list,num):    
    .....    
    .....
```

where my_list is:

```
my_list = [['1','one'],['2','two'],['3','three'],['4','four'],['5','five'],['6','six'],['7','seven'],['8','eight']]
```

I want to split list by given num:

i.e if num = 3
then output will be :  `[[['1','one'],['2','two'],['3','three']],[['4','four'],['5','five'],['6','six']],[['7','seven'],['8','eight']]]`

if num =4 then

```
[[['1','one'],['2','two'],['3','three'],['4','four']],[['5','five'],['6','six'],['7','seven'],['8','eight']]]
```

Comment: @DrTyrsa: That is different. There the chunk size is specified, here the number of chunks.

Comment: @Felix Kling: no, this is exact duplicate.

Comment: @Felix Kling I see two chunks for `num=4`. And you?

Comment: @DrTyrsa: My apologies. I somehow got confused by the two element lists...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd just use a list comprehension/generator:

```
[my_list[x:x+num] for x in range(0, len(my_list), num)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def split_list(lst, num):
    def splitter(lst, num):
        while lst:
            head = lst[:num]
            lst = lst[num:]
            yield head
    return list(splitter(lst, num))
```

Here is an excerpt from running this in the interactive shell:

```
>>> def split_list(lst, num):
...     def splitter(lst, num):
...         while lst:
...             head = lst[:num]
...             lst = lst[num:]
...             yield head
...     return list(splitter(lst, num))
...
>>> split_list(range(10), 3)
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to read this: [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python)